# Convert Page to PersonalWebPartPage

Tags: web-part, development, sharepoint-enterprise

I've a strange question for you. I have to fix bugs in the another's code (webpart for sharepoint 2010). So in the code there is a line with the code below:

```
  var s = (String)((PersonalWebPartPage)Page).Profile["AccountName"][0];
```

and then I tried to view next error appears:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._layouts_wpprevw_aspx' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PersonalWebPartPage'.
```

But this code somehow working on the corporate portal. What it can be? =) Or maybe I've missing some references?

Answer (score 0):

Many kinds of pages can have Web Parts in them. Make sure that the actual page where the Web Part is deployed inherits from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PersonalWebPartPage`.

Look for something like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PersonalWebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```